# Multithreaded read & write of a file , cannot stop operation, writes bad file

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, producer-consumer

I have the task of tranfering large files , files that are about 5 GB in size, therefore a read & write operattion.

I wrote a single threaded version which reads 5k at a time , and immediately writes the 5K to another location, the signle threaded version works fine , I use a zip folder of 412 MB for testing it takes about 5 secs.

My goal is to actually write a multithreaded version , the natural design pattern that came to mind was the producer(reader) consumer(writer) pattern.

Below is first the single threaded version which I based my multithreaded version on:

---

```
   import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ReadWrite {

    URI readFrom = null;
    URI writeTo = null;
    //streams
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    // good buffer size in Java is generally between 2k to 8k
    byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[5 * 1024];
    //just for testing 
    private int readSoFar = 0;
    //const
    ReadWrite(URI readFrom, URI writeTo) {
        this.readFrom = readFrom;
        this.writeTo = writeTo;

    }

    public URI getReadFrom() {
        return readFrom;
    }

    public void setReadFrom(URI readFrom) {
        this.readFrom = readFrom;
    }

    public URI getWriteTo() {
        return writeTo;
    }

    public void setWriteTo(URI writeTo) {
        this.writeTo = writeTo;
    }

    public void process() throws FileNotFoundException {

        // by chunks therefore buffer
        File fileToRead = new File(readFrom);
        File fileToWrite = new File(writeTo);
        try {
            // if read & write destinations exist
            if (fileToRead.exists()) {
                fis = new FileInputStream(fileToRead);
                // instantiate OutputStream

                fos = new FileOutputStream(fileToWrite);
                // read a chunk, then write , update read position, until there
                // is no more to read
                try {
                    int writeCounter = 0;
                    // read
                    while ((fis.read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.length)) != -1) {

                        try {
                            //just for testing & seeing output/progress
                            readSoFar= readSoFar + byteBuffer.length;
                            System.out.println("readSoFar:" + readSoFar);
                            // write
                            fos.write(byteBuffer);
                            // clear previous data
                            Arrays.fill(byteBuffer, (byte) 0);
                            System.out.println("writeCounter: " + writeCounter);
                            writeCounter++;
                        } catch (IOException exc) {
                            exc.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            }
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                try {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }// end class ReadWrite

}
```

---

The main class FileCopy (Single threaded):

```
public class FileCopy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     try {
        try {
            //wls1033_dev.zip
            new ReadWrite( new URI("file:/C:/Users/anaim/Pictures/wls1033_dev.zip"),new URI("file:/C:/Users/anaim/Pictures/result/wls1033_dev.zip")).process();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

}//end main class
```

The output should look something like this:

.
.
.
readSoFar:423198720
writeCounter: 82655
readSoFar:423203840
writeCounter: 82656
readSoFar:423208960
writeCounter: 82657

An obviously the destination file should not be curropted & identical to the original file.

---

Below is the multithreaded version , which is based on the single threaded code , except thread logic & locks via syncronization,wait,notify is implemented. The multithreading is actually working there are no deadlocks, or liveliness issues, however the read/write operation DOES NOT TERMINATE.

The issue seems to be with the variable "**readState" and its getReadState()** method that seems to be not operating correctly when called in the main class, when readState == -1, **than the read/write should terminate.**

Multithreaded read & write (class ReadProducerWriteConsumer) provides a readProcess & writeProcess that wait with synchronized sections based on the value of the "boolean empty" variable/flag

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ReadProducerWriteConsumer {

    URI readFrom = null;
    URI writeTo = null;
    //
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    // good buffer size in Java is generally between 2k to 8k
    byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[1024];
    //
    File fileToRead = null;
    File fileToWrite = null;
    //
    private int readSoFar = 0;
    int writeCounter = 0;
    //
    volatile private int readState = 0;
    // Consumer & Producer state , hence has anything been read in order to be
    // written
    boolean empty = true;

    ReadProducerWriteConsumer(URI readFrom, URI writeTo) {
        this.readFrom = readFrom;
        this.writeTo = writeTo;
        //
        fileToRead = new File(readFrom);
        fileToWrite = new File(writeTo);
    }

    public long getReadState() {
        return this.readState;
    }

    public void setReadState(int readState) {
        this.readState = readState;
    }

    public URI getReadFrom() {
        return readFrom;
    }

    public void setReadFrom(URI readFrom) {
        this.readFrom = readFrom;
    }

    public URI getWriteTo() {
        return writeTo;
    }

    public void setWriteTo(URI writeTo) {
        this.writeTo = writeTo;
    }

    public synchronized void readProcess() throws FileNotFoundException {

        // while false, while data is being written , wait
        while (empty == false) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // by chunks therefore buffer
        File fileToRead = new File(readFrom);

        try {
            // if read & write destinations exist
            if (fileToRead.exists()) {
                fis = new FileInputStream(fileToRead);
                // read a chunk
                try {
                    // while readSoFar!=-1
                    while (((this.readState = fis.read(byteBuffer, 0,
                            byteBuffer.length)) != -1) && empty != false) {

                        // just for testing & seeing output/progress
                        readSoFar = readSoFar + byteBuffer.length;
                        System.out.println("readSoFar:" + readSoFar);

                        // read a chunck , now that buffer is full set emoty to
                        // false
                        empty = false;

                    }
                } catch (IOException exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            }
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                try {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // new data has been read , notify all threads waiting to consume
            // data
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void writeProcess() throws FileNotFoundException {
        // while true, therefore there is nothing to write, wait
        while (empty == true) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // by chunks therefore buffer
        File fileToWrite = new File(writeTo);

        try {
            // instantiate OutputStream
            fos = new FileOutputStream(fileToWrite);
            // then write , update read position

            // write
            try {
                fos.write(byteBuffer);
                // clear previous data
                Arrays.fill(byteBuffer, (byte) 0);
                System.out.println("writeCounter: " + writeCounter);
                writeCounter++;
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();

            }

        } finally {

            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // new data has been written , notify all threads waiting to
            // read/produce more data
            empty = true;
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

}//end class ReadProducerWriteConsumer
```

---

readRunnable class implements a runnable and calls ReadProducerWriteConsumer.readProcess()

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class readRunnable implements Runnable {
    ReadProducerWriteConsumer ReaderProducerWriterConsumer = null;

    public readRunnable(ReadProducerWriteConsumer readerProducerWriterConsumer) {
        super();
        ReaderProducerWriterConsumer = readerProducerWriterConsumer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            ReaderProducerWriterConsumer.readProcess();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // call ReaderProducerWriterConsumer read method
}//end readRunnable class
```

---

writeRunnable class implements a runnable and calls ReadProducerWriteConsumer.writeProcess()

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class writeRunnable implements Runnable
    {
        ReadProducerWriteConsumer ReaderProducerWriterConsumer = null; 

        public writeRunnable (ReadProducerWriteConsumer readerProducerWriterConsumer) {
            super();
            ReaderProducerWriterConsumer = readerProducerWriterConsumer;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                ReaderProducerWriterConsumer.writeProcess();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //ReaderProducerWriterConsumer write method
    }//end writeRunnable
```

---

The main class that instantiates the threads and creates read/write threads until there is no more to read , this condition is checked with the ReadProducerWriteConsumer.getReadState()

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FileCopy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ReadProducerWriteConsumer ReaderProducerWriterConsumer = null;
        try {
            ReaderProducerWriterConsumer = new ReadProducerWriteConsumer(
                    new URI("file:/C:/Users/anaim/Pictures/pic.png"), new URI(
                            "file:/C:/Users/anaim/Pictures/result/pic.png"));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Thread readThread = null;
        Thread writeThread = null;

        while (ReaderProducerWriterConsumer.getReadState() != -1) {

            readThread = new Thread(new readRunnable(
                    ReaderProducerWriterConsumer));

            writeThread = new Thread(new writeRunnable(
                    ReaderProducerWriterConsumer));

            readThread.start();
            writeThread.start();

            try {
                readThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                writeThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



    }

}// end main class
```

Therefore, the  issue with the multithreaded version is that the read/write operation does not stop ,and hence the write operation yields a corrupted file.

Please advise with a intelligent solution. Thanks.

Comment: This code is not correct. You are ignoring the count returned by read(). You must use that as the count argument to write(), with a zero offset argument, instead of assuming that read() filled the buffer. And what makes you think multithreading this is going to make it any faster? Is the disk multi-threaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in your write process, which doesn't loop: it will write only once and then exit, Then the read process will refill the buffer, and wait forever that it becomes empty again.

Besides that, your design is interesting, but a bit unusual.

There are a few problems with it:

- The FileInputStream.read function doesn't necessarily return exactly the number of bytes you requested, and the return value tells you how many were read. You should use that value for your write process.
- You are using a loop to check on the `empty` boolean value as  a lock. It would be easier to use a Semaphore (See [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)),
- Alternatively, you could use the BlockingQueue to synchronize your reads and writes.
- There's also a data structure called the circular buffer which let you store read data in "a continuous manner" within a buffer, but I don't know if it exists in Java. Basically, you keep 2 pointers within your buffer, one which points at the beginning of the free remaining space in the buffer, and one pointing at the beginning of the used space. When you write in the buffer, you start storing data at the position of the free space. If you reach the end of the buffer, you go back to beginning (hence the "circular" idea). You must take care of not passing the used space pointer, but if you're doing your reads correctly (that is, you don't ask for more than the free space you have left), you should be able to avoid that problem. When you read from the buffer, you start from the used space pointer, and read as many bytes as there are available in your buffer. Perhaps you should try that approach at a later stage.